# Raw data redux store

Tags: redux, serialization, redux-toolkit, uint8array

Implementing a local search algorithm with the CSV received from the server, Then encode the CSV file records in a bit sequence for each record. Now I want to access to the series of bit sequences (about 17000 items) with redux. Implementing this with Uint8array rises the "[Non-Serializable Values](https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#why-should-type-be-a-string-or-at-least-serializable-why-should-my-action-types-be-constants)" error. Is any cheap memory way to store that data records in redux?

ps: The byte data will not be edited after initializing and therefore the state will remain constant.

Comment: After digging in the available primitives and technics, I use base64 to store records. Is any way better?